# Como faço para buscar o nome do campo da tabela ao invés do ID quando eu for gravar os dados na minha tabela?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function cadLancamentos(adquirente, formadepagamento, valorformadepagamento, cupomformasdepagamento) {

  var tb = document.getElementById("dtAdquirente");
  var qtdLinhas = tb.rows.length;
  var linha = tb.insertRow(qtdLinhas);

  var cellCodigo = linha.insertCell(0);
  var cellAdquirente = linha.insertCell(1);
  var cellFormadepagamento = linha.insertCell(2);
  var cellValorformadepagamento = linha.insertCell(3);
  var cellCupomformasdepagamento = linha.insertCell(4);

  cellCodigo.innerHTML = qtdLinhas;
  cellAdquirente.innerHTML = adquirente;
  cellFormadepagamento.innerHTML = formadepagamento;
  cellValorformadepagamento.innerHTML = valorformadepagamento;
  cellCupomformasdepagamento.innerHTML = cupomformasdepagamento;
}
```

```html
<div id="dfPessoas">
  <form name="fPessoas">
    <select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="formadepagamento">
      <option selected>Formas de Pagamento</option>
      <option>Elo Crédito</option>
      <!-- com o value informado, ele pega o valor que esta obtido no value -->
      <option>Elo Débito</option>
      <option>Alelo</option>
      <option>Visa</option>
      <option>Visa Electron</option>
      <option>Sodexo</option>
      <option>Mastercard</option>
      <option>Maestro</option>
      <!-- <option value="8">Maestro</option> // Quando remove o "value" ele pega o nome do campo -->
    </select>
    <label for="adquirente">*Adquirente</label>
    <select class='form-control form-control-sm' data-placeholder="Digite um nome p/ procurar o adquirente" name="txtAdquirentes" id="adquirentes"></select>
    <label for="inputAddress">Valor R$</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtValorformadepagamento" class="form-control" id="valorformadepagamento" placeholder="Valor">
    <label for="inputAddress">Cupom</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtCupomformasdepagamento" class="form-control" id="cupomformasdepagamento" placeholder="Cupom">
  </form>
</div><br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <input type="button" value="Adicionar" onclick="cadLancamentos(adquirentes.value, formadepagamento.value, valorformadepagamento.value, cupomformasdepagamento.value)" />
      <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Limpar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <div>
    <table class="table table-dark" id="dtAdquirente">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Codigo:</th>
          <th scope="col">Adquirente:</th>
          <th scope="col">Forma de Pagamento:</th>
          <th scope="col">Valor</th>
          <th scope="col">Cupom</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom seria bom detalhar mais sua dúvida.

Mas vamos tentar, quando você for salvar, você pode fazer uma busca e trazer em um objeto o dado que você precisa.

se tiver usando sequelize você poder fazer assim:

```
const xpto = XPTO.findOne({where:{ id }});
```

o xpto vai ter os dados que você precisa, no where você pode buscar por qualquer atributo que precisar.

Comment: cellAdquirente.innerHTML = ($(adquirente).find('option:selected').text());
e o campo do botão eu só removi o value e deu certo, vlw amigo..

Comment: Que bom @RafaelGuilherme, parabéns, eu tinha entendi algo além, mas você queria pegar o nome que tava na tabela do html... mas que bom que eu certo.

Comment: Isso é que falto mais esclarecimento, como essa foi minha 1 pergunta, eu achei que tinha um limite de caracters pra por...

Comment: Legal, o importante é começar a fazer perguntas...que no caso não tem limites, procure informar o maximo de informações, trechos de códigos, fluxo do que você precisa, para facilitar o entendimento e a ajuda na solução. parabéns... sou novo no stackoverflow tbem